# OKta login - Android

Tags: android, openid-connect, okta

When we are trying to login we are facing the below issue. What could be the reason for this issue.

AuthorizationException: {"type":0,"code":10,"errorDescription":"No compatible browser found"}

1. We tried to set default browser as chrome
2. Tried Okta dependency to the latest one ( implementation 'com.okta.android:okta-oidc-android:1.3.2')

If required any sample code please mention in comment.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I talked to our engineering team at Okta and they said this typically happens in an emulator. They also mentioned this behavior is basically impossible with our new SDK. https://github.com/okta/okta-mobile-kotlin

Comment: @MattRaible I am checking on mobiles only. Only a few mobiles are getting issues. Hope I already used the latest SDK. You are referring kotling sample I am using Java. Am I using the outdated SDK?

Comment: We have new mobile SDKs. Watch our developer blog for a post about it soon. https://developer.okta.com/blog.